# Any alternative to System.exit(STATUS_CODE) or best practice around returning an error code from Java

Tags: java, spring

We have a Java Job which is triggered via Shell Script Utility. And this is scheduled to run at regular intervals.

Now, the shell script requires an exit code, in case the job fails so that it can trigger other alarm points. So, we have System.exit(STATUS_CODE)  in our main class which is called in the catch block when any exception occurs.  The main method looks like below. We are using Spring. We have also configured smtp in the Logger such that all the ERROR level logs are sent via email. Now, we noticed that System.exit abruptly halts logger and other threads as it exits the JVM. So, we added a Thread.sleep(10000) for any logging to complete before calling System.exit.

Is this the best way of sending an ERROR status code to a script from java? Can we send the status without using System.exit call? Any best practice or recommendation when System.exit is required (shudownhook…)? Any alternative in Spring to send error code as the DI container exits?

```
   private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
          LOG.info("Starting Timeout Service...");
          try {
                 final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
                 final SomeBean somebean = ctx.getBean(SomeBean.class);
                 somebean.doSomething();
          } catch (final Exception exception) {
                 LOG.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
                 waitForLogToProcessAndExit();
          }
          LOG.info("Timeout Service Completed");

   }

   private static void waitForLogToProcessAndExit() throws InterruptedException {
          Thread.sleep(10000); //Waiting for any logging to complete before firing System.exit
          System.exit(1);
   }
```

Comment: you can use finally block I guess

Comment: Sorry. Why don't you go through CommandLineJobRunner.class for spring batch. It already implements command executor  with exit code.

Answer (score 0):

And why don't you just simply do every reporting/error handling before calling `System.exit`?
As far as I know there is no other way to force JVM to return exit code other than 0 (as @fge pointed out I am wrong as exceptions would return 1) besides using `System.exit()`
AS logger probalby uses separate thread to send an email, you would eiteher had to wait for it to actually send, or implement email service that would pick up messages to be sent from some sort of queue and run it aside your process (a think this is the best option as it can be used in every component you would need such solution in future).

Comment: Yes there is: exceptions thrown from `main()` will make the JVM exit with 1

Answer (score 0):

(side note: instead of `Thread.sleep(10000)` you can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10)`)

The "bug" here is probably that the logger uses daemon threads; when the JVM exits, it will *not* wait for such threads to complete. The immediate result is that if the thread fails to send your mail before `System.exit()`, you have no mail.

Workarounds:

- from some googling around, I see that with log4j at least, if you have a reference to your appener, `.close()` it before you exit: it will ensure that all messages in the queue are flushed; or maybe you can configure your appender not to use daemon threads in the first place?
- just use plain `cron` with an appropriate `MAILTO` and just log to stdout: `cron` will by default mail the contents of stdout and stderr to the given mail address.